# What happened to the "7 days free" promotion in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Three days ago, I logged into my expired WoW account to see that they were offering me seven free days. Since I was just about to go on a three-day camping trip, I figured I'd claim those days after I returned, but when I logged in today, the offer was gone. What happened to that promotion? The original offer didn't mention a time limit. Did it just move somewhere else, or did it expire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those offers typically have an expiration date, though it may be in small print.

There are a couple possibilities:

1. Blizzard offered [7 free days](http://www.wowheadnews.com/blog=173778/blizzard-offering-7-free-days-to-expired-accounts) back in November in preparation for the Cataclysm release. Not sure why it'd appear this late on your account, but it could just have been an error.
2. I vaguely recall receiving a couple "come back to us" kind of offers on my second (now expired :)) account. It's possible that you received one of those and it also expired.

To be certain, I'd contact [Blizzard's support](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/about/contact.html) and see what they say.

Answer (score 4):

Blizzard removed that program and instead made World of Warcraft entirely free to play until Level 20.

See here: http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=20590&parentCategoryId&pageNumber=1&categoryId=2331

Comment: It was already free until Level 20 the last time I checked, though, and the seven days promotion seemed to be designed more to lure back old players than to attract new people. But I guess it's been discontinued, then.

Comment: @heishe That's different for "come back to us" promotions for existing but expired accounts.

Comment: Err. Different *from*, that is.

Comment: @Cassandrexx - Before the new "Starter" accounts, you could play a Trial account to level 20, but you were still time limited to 10 days.  Now it will allow you to play up to level 20 (and continue playing just without gaining XP) regardless of length the account has been active.